# All displays restart time to time

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure

I have a setup notebook + external LCD. My notebook is almost 7 yrs old now. Time to time both screens turn black and immediately after turn back on. Some of the parts of the screen are distorted and for example web pages need to be reloaded to display properly (re-rendered). Is this a sign of a failing board/graphics card/graphics chip (Intel HD)? IfF yes, how can it be tested?

---

Newest drivers installed.

Comment: Since both screens are distorted, it is most likely the GPU that has failed. That is the common part. Get the manufacturer’s diagnostic app and test the computer hardware.

Comment: I have tried the Intel CPU diag tool - no issues. Dedicated gpu is nVidia. They have no diagnostic tool, but a stress test did not show anything.

Comment: You may need to get the machine serviced to see if a knowledgeable repair person can spot the hardware error. The machine is likely beyond economical repair and probably should be replaced. I have seen older nVidia cards go like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both screens are distorted when the distortion occurs, it most likely means (over 80%) that it is the GPU that is at fault. I have seen older nVidia GPUs fail this way before.

It could be the motherboard (less than 10% in my view) because it would have to be component common to the display (one area of the board) and the video output (another area of the board).

You may need to get the machine serviced to see if a knowledgeable repair person can spot the hardware error. The machine (at 7 years old) is likely beyond economical repair and probably should be replaced.

I trust this helps you.